# unable to call another method within a method in java

Tags: java

I have this class called Date:

```
public class Date {

  // fields

  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  // constructor

  public Date(int month, int day, int year) {
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;
  }

  //check for leap year or not
  public static boolean isLeap(int year) {
    if (year % 4 != 0) {
      return false;
    } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }

  }

  public static boolean isValid(int month, int day, int year) {
    if (year < 1900) {
      return false;
    } else {
      if (month > 0 && month < 13) {
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
          return day > 0 && day <= 31;

        } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
          return day > 0 && day <= 30;
        } else if (month == 2) {
          if (isLeap(year)) {
            return day > 0 && day <= 29;
          } else {
            return day > 0 && day <= 28;
          }
        }

      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public int getMonth() {
    return month
  }

  public void setMonth(int month) {
    this.month = month;
  }

  public int getDay() {
    return day;
  }

  public void setDay(int day) {
    this.day = day;
  }

  public int getYear() {
    return year;
  }

  public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
  }

  public void setDate(int month, int day, int year) {
    if (isValid(month, day, year)) {
      setDay(day);
      setMonth(month);
      setYear(year);
    } else {
      setDay(1);
      setMonth(1);
      setYear(1900);
    }
  }
//

  public String displayDate() {
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }

  public String add(int n) {
    if (n <= 20) {
      if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
        if ((day + n > 0) && (day + n <= 31))
          day = day + n;
        else
          month += 1;
        if (month > 12)
          year += 1;
      }
      if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        if ((day + n > 0) && (day + n <= 30))
          day = day + n;
        else
          month += 1;
        if (month > 12)
          year += 1;
      }
    }
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }

  public String sub(int n) {
    if (n <= 20) {
      if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
        if (day - n < 0)
          day = 31 + day - n;
        else
          month -= 1;
      if (month < 0)
        year -= 1;
      if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        if ((day - n < 0))
          day = 30 + day - n;
        else
          month -= 1;
      if (month < 0)
        year -= 1;

    }
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }

}
```

And this class to to test the Date class:

```
public class MyDateTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyDateTester();
    }

    Date theClass;

    public MyDateTester(){
        theClass = new Date(6,1,1600);
        System.out.print("Month is: ");
        System.out.println(theClass.getMonth());
        System.out.print("Day is: ");
        System.out.println(theClass.getDay());
        System.out.print("Year is: ");
        System.out.println(theClass.getYear());
        System.out.println(theClass.displayDate());
        System.out.println(theClass.add(20));
        System.out.println(theClass.isValid(6,1,2000));
    }
}
```

When I give 6, 1, 1600 values to Date, it is still printing 6,1,1600, isValid method in setDate method is not setting the dates right. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason why you use a custom date implementation when the JDK has a builtin `Date` (which implements `Comparable` of itself to boot)?

Comment: do you get any error or warining?

Comment: you have to use the class name to call the static function.eg if isValid belongs to class A then A.isValid(month,day,year) is the correct way to call the method.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not evaluating"? Do you get a compile error? Does it always return true, or always return false?

Comment: (Additionally, please edit your post to be indented more usefully. It's very hard to read at the moment.)

Comment: isValid works, when I try to call this within setDate method, it is not working. I am not getting any errors.

Comment: @ntstha, setDate and isValid are both part of the same class Date.

Comment: so did you try calling the method like Date.isValid()?

Comment: Can you paste a test case? That will be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it is not working"?

Comment: I just pasted the test class. when I pass, 6,1, 1600, I still get this output. I ti should be 1, 1, 1900.

Comment: Do you get an Exception / stack trace when running it? The phrases "is not working" and "evaluate" are useless at conveying your problem...

Comment: Technically, you should have `Date.isValid(6,1,2000)` and not `theClass.isValid(6,1,2000)`. Better practice to reference static mthods to the class, not an instance of the class

Comment: @ktm5124, not working mean, given the month, day, and year setDate method is not evaluating to be right.

Comment: Better post an SSCCE than these code fragments...

Comment: Does your Date class constructor call setDate()? Are you using your Date constructor, or importing java.util.Date?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling a static method by `theClass.isValid(...)`. You can technically do it but it makes no sense. Use: `Date.isValid(...)` and be careful not to import `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @rolfl, I can do that in my test class. But How do I call isValid in my setDate method?

Comment: Okay, I posted the answer. Thanks for providing more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, you're creating a date with its constructor. Your constructor does not call `setDate()` or `isValid().`

```
 public Date(int month, int day, int year){
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;
 }
```

You can solve this most easily by calling `setDate()` in the Date constructor.'

```
 public Date(int month, int day, int year){
    setDate( month, day, year );
 }
```

Comment: Thomax-Cramer, I really have one other question. I have another method called add. providing number to add, I need to add that number to the date and return the latest month, day, and year. I have the method written. But when I do this "        System.out.println(Date.sub(20));", in my tester class, I get this error: "non-static method sub(int) cannot be referenced from a static context". what does this mean, how would get around this error?

Comment: Your method sub() is likely an instance method. You can call an instance method through a reference pointing to an instance of the class. In your example above, that's your variable "theClass". So you can use theClass.sub(20) . (Also, consider changing the name of your instance variable -- it's not referencing a class, it's referencing an instance of a class.)

Comment: that's what I am doing here "System.out.println(theClass.add(20));", I get that cannot be reference error.

Comment: Both your subtract() and add() methods should be declared without static, and called through the Date instance referenced by "theClass". In general, methods can either be static, and called via the name of the class, or non-static, and called on a reference to an instance of the class.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you must call your setDate() method inside your constructor for Date